# Errors thrown on Nuxt Server Routes don't trigger the Error Page

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

(Minimal Repro included at the bottom.)

Hey all.
Thanks for reading this. I am actually not sure if I misunderstood the documentation or if I am experiencing a true Nuxt Bug:

This is what I am experiencing:
I can trigger the Nuxt Error Page from anywhere inside my Application just fine.
So an Error that gets thrown properly also opens the Error Handler Page and can be dealt with there.
But when I throw an Error on one of the Server Routes it only logs it to the Servers Console and does not trigger any errors.

I realize that the /server directory is outside of my Nuxt Application and gets executed somewhere inside Nitro. But according to this documentation (https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#error-page) Server API Routes in the Nitro Lifecycle should also trigger the Error Page, correct?

But all it does is return the Error inside of the useFetch Object.
I could just watch that Object and throw another Error as soon as useFetch reports one, but I would much rather have it happen automatically because, in my current Project, there are quite a few server routes.

I made a Minimal Repro here so you can see what I mean:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/server-route-error

So did I misunderstand the documentation or do I create an issue on the Nuxt Repo?